# Have buttons inline with a form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project where I need to make a sort of date picker. To do this I want to have a forward and back button, with a form containing a hidden field in between. However when I do this the buttons end up on top and below the form. My code is as follows:

```
<span style="display: inline;">
    <button class = 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'><%= back %></button>
        <%= form_tag year_path, class: "form-inline", remote: true, method: :put do %>
            <%= @year %>
        <% end %>
    <button class = 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'><%= forward %></button>
</span>
```

How do I make it so that the buttons appear on either side of the year?

Comment: Please put a display inline on button tag and for tag because button tag and form tag are display block which takes full row